# AFHTTPRequestOperation works fine but AFHTTPSessionManager doesn't work

Tags: ios, soap, wsdl, afnetworking

I am doing an SOAP request with a web service using AFNetworking2.2.1 .I have read the documentation on AFNetworking, it says that Although `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is usually the best way to go about making requests, `AFHTTPRequestOperation` can be used by itself.It means that the recommended way is using the `AFHTTPSessionManager`.First, I use the `AFHTTPSessionManager`,but it doesn't work.Then I tried `AFHTTPRequestOperation`,it works fine.This really confused me.

Here are the two code snapshots.It doesn't work when using `AFHTTPSessionManager`,while it works fine with `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

My question is why AFHTTPSessionManager doesn't work and how to change it.

```
[[SLAppNetAPIClient sharedClient] POST:@"webservices/wsLogin.php?wsdl" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             "<DGLogInWork xmlns=\"http://10.0.0.22:3301/\">\n"
                             "<szHostName>%@</szHostName>\n"
                             "<szLoginMAC>%@</szLoginMAC>\n"
                             "<szLoginIP>%@</szLoginIP>\n"
                             "</DGLogInWork>\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n", [SLDevice name], [SLDevice deviceMAC], [SLDevice deviceIP]];
    debugLog(@"soapMessage:%@", soapMessage);
    NSDictionary *header = @{@"Content-Type": @"text/xml"};
    NSData *body = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:header body:body];
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    debugLog(@"responseObject~~~: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    debugLog(@"error :%@", error);
}];
```

This is using the `AFHTTPSessionManager`.`SLAppNetAPIClient` is a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.0.22:3301/webservices/wsLogin.php?wsdl"]];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<DGLogInWork xmlns=\"http://10.0.0.22:3301/\">\n"
                         "<szHostName>%@</szHostName>\n"
                         "<szLoginMAC>%@</szLoginMAC>\n"
                         "<szLoginIP>%@</szLoginIP>\n"
                         "</DGLogInWork>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n", [SLDevice name], [SLDevice deviceMAC], [SLDevice deviceIP]];
[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    debugLog(@"responseObject = %@", [operation responseString]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    debugLog(@"error = %@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

This is using `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

I don't know what the difference between them.Hope someone could help.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I also don't understand the difference between Session Manager and Request Operation.

Comment: If someone answers this, you may find the help as well [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389940/afhttpsessionmanager-to-use-soap-based-service)