# AFHTTPSessionManager to use SOAP based service

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, afnetworking, afhttpsessionmanager

I checked few posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181844/how-to-convert-afnetworking-service-invoke-to-use-afhttpsessionmanager) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523091/afhttprequestoperation-works-fine-but-afhttpsessionmanager-doesnt-work)) in Stackoverflow but none of them answered "How to use `AFHTTPSessionManager` to use SOAP based web service".

Is it not possible or we need to do some tweaking like subclassing etc?

I can call the SOAP based using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` but this is what I don't want to use since I have XML & JSON web services there I am using `AFHTTPSessionManager`. I want to have similar approach throughout my application.

My codes using `RequestOperation` is :

```
NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">n"
"<soap:Body>\n"
"<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
"<Celsius>50</Celsius>\n"
"</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
"</soap:Body>\n"
"</soap:Envelope>n";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tempuri.org/"]];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", [operation responseString]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

I tried using `SessionManager` but this doesn't work: (the `request` is same as in above code snippet), I get `data` as `nil` and `response` has some values, also the `error` has some values in it.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *sManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];

[sManager dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
            completionHandler:^( NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

                NSLog(@"Data: %@", data);
                NSLog(@"Resp: %@", response);
                NSLog(@"Err: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: check your content type as  [request setValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  The above code works but it uses `RequestOpeation`, I want to achieve the same with `SessionManager` of `AFNetworking` class.

Comment: No senior, I also tried more than 1 hour I also not get answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried for multiple hours and finally was able to get some response and no-error. Here is the updated code:

```
NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">n"
"<soap:Body>\n"
"<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
"<Celsius>50</Celsius>\n"
"</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
"</soap:Body>\n"
"</soap:Envelope>n";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tempuri.org/"]];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


AFHTTPSessionManager *sManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
sManager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [sManager dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
            completionHandler:^( NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error){
                NSString *resString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Data: %@", resString);
                //NSLog(@"Resp: %@", [response ]);
                NSLog(@"Err: %@", error);
            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: I have implemented the above code but how can I implement NSOperationQueue in above code?